# Clear cached URL redirects from Safari and Firefox

Tags: firefox, redirection, cache, safari, browser-cache

I have a NodeJS server and set up a redirect for `https://emocoes.org/ukraine` to `https://emocoes.org/ucrania`. The redirects seem set up correctly:

```
$ wget https://emocoes.org/ukraine 2>&1 | grep Location:
Location: /ucrania [following]

$ wget https://emocoes.org/ucrania 2>&1 | grep Location:
```

On Firefox and Safari, which I often use, the browsers redirect both URLs to the home page. On Opera, which I seldom use, the redirects work well.

I clear the whole cache of Firefox (`Clear data` at `about:preferences#privacy`), restart Firefox, and enter the URL again. It still redirects to the home page. Safari does the same after I delete the data for this website.

How can I delete the cache, test the website, and be sure that the redirects work well?